# getting typoscript values in ext_table.php

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-tca

I am new to typo3 extension development, And i want get the typoscript values inside ext_table.php . Is there any good value to implement this this .This is my ext_tables.php file . I want to get typoscript values here. 
`

```
    <?php
    if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
   }

    // get extension confArr
    $confArr = unserialize($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf']['pits_documents']);

$tempColumns = array (
    'tx_pitsdocuments_languages' => array (     
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_languages',     
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_dam_cat',    
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_dam_cat.parent_id='.$confArr['langcat'].' AND tx_dam_cat.sys_language_uid=0 ORDER BY tx_dam_cat.uid', 
            'size' => 5,    
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 99,   
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING'  => 2,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'list' => array(
                    'type'   => 'script',
                    'title'  => 'List',
                    'icon'   => 'list.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_dam_cat',
                        'pid'   => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    ),
                    'script' => 'wizard_list.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_pitsdocuments_supplier' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_supplier',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'select',
      'foreign_table' => 'tx_dam_cat',  
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_dam_cat.parent_id='.$confArr['supplycat'].' AND tx_dam_cat.sys_language_uid=0 ORDER BY tx_dam_cat.uid',   
            'size' => 8,    
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,    
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING'  => 2,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'list' => array(
                    'type'   => 'script',
                    'title'  => 'List',
                    'icon'   => 'list.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_dam_cat',
                        'pid'   => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    ),
                    'script' => 'wizard_list.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_pitsdocuments_businessunit' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_businessunit',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'select',
      /* 'items' => array (
                array('',0),
            ), */   
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_dam_cat',    
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_dam_cat.parent_id='.$confArr['businesscat'].' AND tx_dam_cat.sys_language_uid=0 ORDER BY tx_dam_cat.uid', 
            'size' => 8,    
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,    
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING'  => 2,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'list' => array(
                    'type'   => 'script',
                    'title'  => 'List',
                    'icon'   => 'list.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_dam_cat',
                        'pid'   => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    ),
                    'script' => 'wizard_list.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype' => array (        
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype',        
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'check',
            'cols' => 4,
            'items' => array (
                array('LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype.I.0', '1'),
                array('LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype.I.1', '2'),
                array('LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype.I.2', '3'),
            ),
        )
    ),
    'tx_pitsdocuments_doctypes' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.tx_pitsdocuments_doctypes',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'select',
      /* 'items' => array (
                array('',0),
            ), */   
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_dam_cat',    
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_dam_cat.parent_id='.$confArr['doctypecat'].' AND tx_dam_cat.sys_language_uid=0 ORDER BY tx_dam_cat.uid',  
            'size' => 8,    
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,    
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING'  => 2,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'list' => array(
                    'type'   => 'script',
                    'title'  => 'List',
                    'icon'   => 'list.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_dam_cat',
                        'pid'   => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    ),
                    'script' => 'wizard_list.php',
                ),
            ),
        )
    ),
);


t3lib_div::loadTCA('tx_dam');
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('tx_dam',$tempColumns,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_dam','--div--;LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam.div_overview,tx_pitsdocuments_foldertype;;;;1-1-1, tx_pitsdocuments_languages, tx_pitsdocuments_supplier, tx_pitsdocuments_businessunit, tx_pitsdocuments_doctypes');

$tempColumnscat = array (
      'global_id' => array(
            'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
            'l10n_display' => 'defaultAsReadonly',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tx_dam_cat.global_id',
            'config' => $GLOBALS['T3_VAR']['ext']['dam']['TCA']['category_config'],
        ),
);


t3lib_div::loadTCA('tx_dam_cat');
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('tx_dam_cat',$tempColumnscat,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_dam_cat','global_id','','after:parent_id');


t3lib_extMgm::addPlugin(array(
    'LLL:EXT:pits_documents/locallang_db.xml:tt_content.list_type_pi1',
    $_EXTKEY . '_pi1',
    t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'ext_icon.gif'
),'list_type');

?>
`
```

Comment: I do not think that is possible, because the file is included during bootstrap of the framework. Also note that your extension might be called in the backend (e.g. to create records). There is not FE context in backend. On top of that you should explain what you really want to archive, otherwise it is not possible to suggest a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @pgampe  i want to limit the entries in the limit box for each domain. The site in which i am working has 60+ domains , SO i want to limit the entries in that 4 select box for each domain. Also can you please given me an idea to get the BACKEND logged in users details in ext_tables.php

Comment: Create a user function hand a custom wizard and do not try to make the static ``TCA`` dynamic. There a few markers you can use. Check the ``TCA Refrence`` For more information about the ``TCA``. It should also contain a few words about wizards, otherwise have loop at the ``API Documentation`` - all below http://typo3.org/documentation/

Comment: @pgampe: Is there any way to get the current backend language typo3 in ext_table.php file just like `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid`

Comment: No, because the TCA is included very early in the bootstrap. But the userfunction is run later, thus create a userfunction.

Answer (score 1):

In the wizard you should be able to get the id of the page which is edited ($this-id ? have a look into the [API](http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classt3lib___s_cbase.html)). You do not need to send it as an parameter in the configuration.

And you can use markers in foreign_table_where but afaik not in the wizard itself - have a look into the [TCA](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.7.1/view/1/3/).